# To merge software solutions or not?

Tags: migration, backend

Software A is a Node/Express application using a MongoDB database.  It is accessed mostly via RESTful endpoint by a mobile app built in RN and an admin dashboard via React web app.  It also has a graphql endpoint beginning to be built to replace specific REST endpoints.

Software B is the acquired software solution built via React web app using Firebase (Firestore DB) solution. It uses other convenience features like Google and Facebook OAuth.  Software B has not officially entered the market yet.

Software A has features that software B does not have.  Software B has features that A does not.  However, the goal is to create a “seamless user experience bringing together features of both Software A and B”.

My big question is around the following:

- Do you keep these backend solutions separate or merge them into one backend (I.e. take Firestore logic and re-create on API and Mongo)?
- What are the trade offs of each?  (I.e. which is more manageable long term?)

Merge into one collective database and API:
**Pros**:

- Advanced data queries become easier for related data
- More manageable long term to have one database solution rather than several.
- Firestore will likely need to be migrated off of in the future anyway
- Easier to optimize one solution rather than two separate databases.  Example give me all data from A and then merge that with data from B then send to Frontend

**Cons**:

- More development time to now move data structure and logic of B onto A backend.

**Conclusion**:
My belief is that it would be worth the short term cost of moving over software B logic to software A backend because the data will be easier to access in a unified way. It also will be easier to migrate off Firebase now rather than a future where many users are using it (our business case is pretty solid that there will be many users).

I’m happy to supply additional information if it gives a more concise picture.  (feel free to correct me if I am mistaken in any of my above points).  This is the first time I’m involved in the integration of two different softwares so am learning this as I go.

Comment: In the era of micro services, why bother merging these at all?

Comment: Not to say it’s not a possibility.  I guess my thought would be if the data from A is related to B and commonly going to be pulled together it would make sense to have it related on one database for performance reasons.  Again I could be wrong in this assumption.

Comment: _"Software A has features that software B does not have. Software B has features that A does not."_ Does this imply that A and B have overlapping features as well? Whose implementation wins out in your proposed merge? Always A? Always B? Selectively? A and B both allowed at the same time, one failing over for the other? ...

Comment: _"More manageable long term to have one database solution rather than several."_ Can you back this claim up? More often than not, the precise opposite is observed, whereby monoliths are inherently considered to be _less_ maintainable, not more.

Comment: _"Advanced data queries become easier for related data"_ Does this imply that you're moving towards having features that strongly depend on a combination of both A-only and B-only features? Because if that's the case, then you have a new set of C features who can only depend on the concurrent existence of A and B - this is not the same as having a bundles set of A features and B features.

Comment: @Flater There are overlapping features.  In terms of which wins it's hard to say at this point.  B is based around event management whereas A is discoverability and creation as of now.  A has been around longer and thus has immediate users already.  Adding feature sets of B would enhance the features in A but also could be extensible to other markets that A is immediately not.

Comment: @Flater I'll give a use case that makes me think this in our situation though I could possibly be thinking about this incorrectly.  This may also answer your last point.  Say I create an event in A.  That allows everyone using the mobile app to see said event and when it takes place, location etc.  B has features such as event management (collect registration, track win loss, create teams etc.) Those types of information will always be related directly to the event that was created in A.  To keep those types of things in sync when they live in two different places seems more difficult.

Comment: @Flater i.e. to above for advanced query:  "Give me events within 25 miles of my location (A) and populate registration info with team names (B)".  If there was one merged database, this query becomes easier to comprehend and create as you don't have to worry about merging the data stored in one into the data stored in the other.  

The other worry I have here is the limitation of B using Firebase and its ability to support more complex querying on its dataset.